# pointing to a different yum repository

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, fedora, rpm, yum

I am not sure if this is possible or if there's any easier way but I am trying to install a software package but its not available when I search for it within Yum.  I read their documentation and they seem to have a fedora package which I think amazon's ec2 linux image is based on(or cent os).

If I just change my repository to point to fedora or download the rpm, would that work? Or would that break something?

Comment: actually i figured out how to install the software but i'm still wondering if its possible to mix rpm files between distro?  I know suse and redhat, for example, don't mix but what about distro's that are both suse based or both redhat based, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is this application?

what you can do:

1. you have rpm file
   $ wget [link to rpm file]
   $ su -c 'yum --nogpgcheck localinstall [path to my rpm]
2. rpm is in testing
   $ su -c 'yum install --enablerepo=updates-testing [application name]
3. You have source application
   $ read README file and follow indication

Comment: perfect.  This is what I was looking for.  Thanks Bioinfomatics!!